# Writing on Emacs: Spell + Grammar + More checking?

Tags: flyspell, spell-checking, hunspell, writing

There is something I never found how to manage correctly on Emacs: advance spell checking.

I know that a lot of modes allow spell check (flyspell, hunspell...) but what I really wonder is: is it possible to reach a Microsoft Word spell/grammar checking level in Emacs? And more than that, is it possible to even go further and provide advanced assistance with synonyms or sentences diversity like some software like [Antidote](https://www.antidote.info/en/antidote-10) could provide?

In all the talks / tutorials about "writing books using Emacs" I saw, nothing was really clear about spell checking :S

Bonus point: what if I write in French?

Edit:
Example of inputs that would be checked/fixed:

> This is you're money.
>
> This is they giant octopus.

Comment: Can you add a simple example of "bad" input, and what hints you'd expect to receive?

Comment: I've edited the post. @dominela10

Comment: A short web-search delivered: https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-langtool See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LanguageTool#cite_note-13

Comment: Thanks for your help folks!